# How can I change the datetime values in a pandas df?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe and datetime is used as an index in the following format: datetime.date(2018, 12, 31).

Each datetime represents the fiscal year end, i.e. 31/12/2018, 31/12/2017, 31/12/2016 etc.

However, for some companies the fiscal year end may be 30/11/2018 or 31/10/2018 and etc. instead of the last date of each year.

Is there any quick way in changing the non-standardized datetime to the last date of each year? 
i.e. from 30/11/2018 to 30/12/2018 and 31/10/2018 to 31/12/2018 an so on.....

Comment: Can you just discard everything but the year? Something like ``df.index = df.index.apply(lambda dt: dt.year)``?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot do that because some companies report the financial statements quarterly i.e 31/03/2018, 31/07/2018, 30/09/2018, 31/12/2018 and the corresponding inconsistent dates may be 30/04/2018, 31/08/2018, 31/11/2018 and 31/01/2019. The inconsistent dates vary based on each companies spec. Let' s say that the inconsistent dates are totally randomized.  What needs to be done is identify the year, month date and shift each inconsistent date to the most common pattern (i.e. end of March, July, September and December). A for loop solution inside the df would probably be a disaster

Comment: Then some sort of ceiling... ``lambda dt: datetime.datetime(year=dt.year, month=(dt.month // 4) * 4)`` or something of that sort. I'm guessing you end up with some simple function that you want to ``.apply`` to the index, just not totally sure how you want to define that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': ['2019-01-02','2019-02-01', '2019-04-01', '2019-06-01', '2019-11-30','2019-12-30'],
                  'data': [1,2,3,4,5,6]})

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

df['quarter'] = df['datetime'] + pd.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd(n=0)

df

     datetime  data  quarter
0   2019-01-02  1   2019-03-31
1   2019-02-01  2   2019-03-31
2   2019-04-01  3   2019-06-30
3   2019-06-01  4   2019-06-30
4   2019-11-30  5   2019-12-31
5   2019-12-30  6   2019-12-31
```

We have a datetime column with random dates I picked. Then we add a timeseries offset to the end of each date to make it quarter end and standardize the times.